# Как передвинуть svg иконки внутрь?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Как передвинуть svg  иконки внутрь?
margin & padding толкают только до уровня как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.zoom {
  position: absolute;
  padding: -100px -100px;
  margin: 13px
}

.voice {
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin: 13px
}

.bar {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <svg focusable="false" class="zoom">
    <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
  </svg>
  
  <input type="text" style="border:none;">
  
  <svg focusable="false" class="voice">
    <path d="m12 15c1.66 0 3-1.31 3-2.97v-7.02c0-1.66-1.34-3.01-3-3.01s-3 1.34-3 3.01v7.02c0 1.66 1.34 2.97 3 2.97z" fill="#4285f4"></path>
    <path d="m11 18.08h2v3.92h-2z" fill="#34a853"></path>
    <path d="m7.05 16.87c-1.27-1.33-2.05-2.83-2.05-4.87h2c0 1.45 0.56 2.42 1.47 3.38v0.32l-1.15 1.18z" fill="#f4b400"></path>
    <path d="m12 16.93a4.97 5.25 0 0 1 -3.54 -1.55l-1.41 1.49c1.26 1.34 3.02 2.13 4.95 2.13 3.87 0 6.99-2.92 6.99-7h-1.99c0 2.92-2.24 4.93-5 4.93z" fill="#ea4335"></path>
  </svg>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Для этого есть свойство z-index

Comment: @kiten не работает

Comment: Вверху вашего CSS добавьте `* { border: 1px solid red; }` Окажется, что SVG-элемент большущий такой прямоугольник) К нему и применяются все margin, поэтому получается не то, что ожидалось. `width: 25px; height: 25px;` в ответе @UModeL как-раз решает эту проблему.

Comment: Кроме того, `input` тоже выплывает за пределы .bar. Я бы и его сделал с `position: absolute;` и всем элементам с абсолютным позиционированием задал отступы при помощи свойств: top, right, bottom и left вместо маргинов и педдингов.

Answer (score 5):

```css
.bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%; left: 30%;
  width: 40%; height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.input,
.zoom,
.voice {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; width: 25px; height: 25px;
}
.input {
  left: 50%; width: calc(100% - 100px);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: none;
}
.zoom {
  left: 0%; transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
.voice {
  right: 0%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bar">
    <svg focusable="false" class="zoom">
      <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
    </svg>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <svg focusable="false" class="voice">
      <path d="m12 15c1.66 0 3-1.31 3-2.97v-7.02c0-1.66-1.34-3.01-3-3.01s-3 1.34-3 3.01v7.02c0 1.66 1.34 2.97 3 2.97z" fill="#4285f4"></path>
      <path d="m11 18.08h2v3.92h-2z" fill="#34a853"></path>
      <path d="m7.05 16.87c-1.27-1.33-2.05-2.83-2.05-4.87h2c0 1.45 0.56 2.42 1.47 3.38v0.32l-1.15 1.18z" fill="#f4b400"></path>
      <path d="m12 16.93a4.97 5.25 0 0 1 -3.54 -1.55l-1.41 1.49c1.26 1.34 3.02 2.13 4.95 2.13 3.87 0 6.99-2.92 6.99-7h-1.99c0 2.92-2.24 4.93-5 4.93z" fill="#ea4335"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я сравнил как у google и сделал - вроде похоже - говорите если что то не так

```css
.bar {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.bar input {
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}

svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <svg class="zoom" viewBox="0 0 28 25" width="40" fill="#ccc">
    <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
  </svg>

  <input type="text">

  <svg class="voice" viewBox="0 0 28 25" width="40">
    <path d="m12 15c1.66 0 3-1.31 3-2.97v-7.02c0-1.66-1.34-3.01-3-3.01s-3 1.34-3 3.01v7.02c0 1.66 1.34 2.97 3 2.97z" fill="#4285f4"></path>
    <path d="m11 18.08h2v3.92h-2z" fill="#34a853"></path>
    <path d="m7.05 16.87c-1.27-1.33-2.05-2.83-2.05-4.87h2c0 1.45 0.56 2.42 1.47 3.38v0.32l-1.15 1.18z" fill="#f4b400"></path>
    <path d="m12 16.93a4.97 5.25 0 0 1 -3.54 -1.55l-1.41 1.49c1.26 1.34 3.02 2.13 4.95 2.13 3.87 0 6.99-2.92 6.99-7h-1.99c0 2.92-2.24 4.93-5 4.93z" fill="#ea4335"></path>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно сделать так: в .bar добавить две строки:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
```

А в .voice изменить:

```
margin: 13px 13px 13px 35px;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]